# Is Samba required if you don't share folders and don't have any printers?

Tags: samba, cleanup, boot-time

I wish to remove all unnecessary packages and services from Ubuntu 12.04. I was not clear whether samba is required for things other than sharing folders and printing. I don't do either of these tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not required. Note that "shared folders" also covers "mapped drives."

Comment: Tom - So if I remove samba using BUM, it would not affect mapped drivers?

Comment: Samba is used to create shared folders (a.k.a. mapped drives) and shared printers between Linux and Windows. If you need/use mapped drives, do not remove samba.

Comment: Hope "Mapped drives" does not refer to mounted partitions or external usb devices, right?

Comment: Correct, mounted partitions are not the same as mapped drives.

Comment: Your original question has been answered, correct? If so, this question should be closed, and marked completed/answered.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you do not have Samba installed.

*Clarified:* If you haven't had need of Samba's feature, Samba would not be installed.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: @StephenMyall This is not a comment. The author is saying that if you never set up folder or printers sharing, then Samba is not installed. I'm not sure that's necessarily true, but this is an answer to the question (which is about removing packages and services that are not needed).